# can't receive JS variable values in PHP using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a Javascript variable to a php file. Everething is ok in the JS side, I receive a msg that data is sent, but in the php side nothing happen, here is my JS code:

```
$(".add-to-cart").click(function(event){


    event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
type: "POST",// see also here
url: 'c.php',// and this path will be proper
data: {
       source1: "some text",
       source2: "some text 2"}
}).done(function( msg )
      {
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );// see alert is come or not
     });

});
```

and the php code:

```
<?php
$src1= $_POST['source1'];  
$src2= $_POST['source2'];     

echo $src1; 
echo $src2;
?>
```

Comment: check for errors and look at your console.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: Everything is ok in browser's developer tools (JS side), and I,ve already included the jQuery library. the problem is in the php side

Answer (score 1):

Try it with:

```
method: "POST"
```

Not instead or with the type param too.
From jquery docs:

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

But it doesn't meantion type is not working in newer versions, at least this is what I experienced.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1) create a file output.log

In you PHP file

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$stream = json_encode($data);
$request = json_encode($_REQUEST);
file_put_contents('output.log', "$stream\n$request);
```

If non output, then is something wrong between your web page and php. probably routeS?

As you send a object, probably you get a stream

Comment: I got this : "" [] in the output file ?!

Comment: Because you are not receiving any data. can you press 12 --> go to console tab and try this http://pastebin.com/c8udThgc

Comment: I tried the code in the console tab, I receive this: Object {readyState: 1} source1source1, But I'm still can't get data in the php file

Comment: that is a problem. a ready state 1 is opened comm. but real response only at state 4 , even state 2 es when sends